# how to click a link with jquery contains

Tags: jquery

I have a link that i am trying to emulate a click on. I am using the following code but nothing happens when I execute the script. Any ideas?

Code

```
$("a:contains('somewebsite')").click();
```

Link

```
 <a href="http://somewebsite.com/radio.php">Radio</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) checks for text content.  You want an [`attribute contains`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector:

```
$("a[href*='somewebsite']").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

[:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) will check the contents of the text value, which in this case would be "Radio". So this would work:

```
$("a:contains('Radio')").click();
```

What you're after, more likely though, is using an [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
$("a[href*='somewebsite']").click();
```

Which will click a links which an href ([href]) attribute that contains ([href*=""]) somewebsite.

Comment: You linked :contains and attribute contains selector to the same thing, but said they were different...

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off assigning a class or ID to the link. It will be simpler and faster.

```
<a id="webLink" href="http://somewebsite.com/radio.php">Radio</a>
```

Script:

```
$("#webLink").click();
```

Is there a reason why this method would not be best for you?

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
$('a[href*="somewebsite"]').click();
```

instead. As you're using it, it checks for text contents of the tag, not the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("a[href*='somewebsite']").click();
```